# Не получается сгенерить grpc файлы для го

Tags: golang, grpc, google-protobuf, protoc

Есть директория

```
├── cmd
│   └── main.go
├── go.mod
└── proto
    └── forward.proto
```

прописываю в терминале

```
protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
    --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
    proto/forward.proto
```

Получаю ошибку

> protoc-gen-go: invalid Go import path "forward" for
> "proto/forward.proto"
>
> The import path must contain at least one forward slash ('/')
> character.
>
> See
> https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#package
> for more information.
>
> --go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1. a.mamedov@a-mamedov forward-spinner %

Как ее устранить и сгенерить grpc для файла forward.proto?

Comment: попробуйте так `protoc -I./ -I$(GOPATH)/src  --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative  proto/forward.proto `

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, теперь говорит zsh: command not found: GOPATH
/src: warning: directory does not exist.
protoc-gen-go: invalid Go import path "forward" for "proto/forward.proto"

Comment: так и пишет, что не настроен GOPATH. настройте и попробуйте снова